# Error with this PHP config file

Tags: php

Hello I'm trying to make a simple configuration file for my app
my project folder is:
inside folder 'app'
       -Config.php
inside root directory:
-index.php
-config.php

this is how config.php looks like:

```
<?php  
return [
    'db' => [
        'hosts' => [
            'local' => 'localhost',
            'externo' => '1.1.1.1',
        ],
        'name' => 'db-stats',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root'
    ],
    'mail' => [
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com'
    ]
];

?>
```

Config.php is:

```
<?php 
namespace Project\Helpers;
class Config
{
    protected $data;
    protected $default = null;
    public function load($file){
        $this->$data = require $file;
    }
    public function get($key, $default = null){
        $this->$default = $default;
        $segments = explode('.', $key);
        $data = $this->$data;

        foreach ($segments as $segment) {
            if(isset($data[$segment])){
                $data = $data[$segment];
            }else{
                $data = $this->$default;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
    public function exists($key){
        return $this->get($key) !== $this->$default;
    }
}
?>
```

and finally index.php:

```
<?php 

use Project\Helpers\Config;
require 'app/Config.php';

$config = new Config;
$config->load('config.php');

echo $config->get('db.hosts.local');

?>
```

the thing is I'm getting this 2 errors when I run the page:

> Notice: Undefined variable: data in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\probar\app\Config.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\probar\app\Config.php on line 11

please help me what's is wrong with this???

Answer (score 1):

`$this->data = require $file;` not <strike>$this->$data = require $file;</strike>.

And `$this->default = $default;` instead of <strike>$this->$default = $default;</strike>

Otherwise those would be [variable variables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
<?php 
namespace Project\Helpers;
class Config
{
    protected $data;
    protected $default = null;
    public function load($file){
        $this->data = require $file;
    }
    public function get($key, $default = null){
        $this->default = $default;
        $segments = explode('.', $key);
        $data = $this->data;

        foreach ($segments as $segment) {
            if(isset($data[$segment])){
                $data = $data[$segment];
            }else{
                $data = $this->default;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
    public function exists($key){
        return $this->get($key) !== $this->default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a synthax error in the class constructor. In PHP, when you access a member attribute with the `->` operator, you don't have to use the `$` modifier.

The correct code looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Project\Helpers;
class Config
{
    protected $data;
    protected $default = null;
    public function load($file){
        $this->data = require $file;
    }
    public function get($key, $default = null){
        $this->default = $default;
        $segments = explode('.', $key);
        $data = $this->data;

        foreach ($segments as $segment) {
            if(isset($data[$segment])){
                $data = $data[$segment];
            }else{
                $data = $this->default;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
    public function exists($key){
        return $this->get($key) !== $this->default;
    }
}
```